# Android Studio Asks to "Update google-services plugin or updating com.google.android.gms" for Firebase Auth and database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I am integrating Firebase Database and Authentication to my Android Project. I get the following error:

***Error:org.gradle.api.GradleException: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.4.0***.

My app build.gradle file is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.antoinecampbell.firebase.demo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I know that I am mixing old and new version of dependencies, but can't figure out how to solve it.
I will try to make this question as helpful as I can by editing it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dependency to Google-services to your **root** `build.gradle`. This file is different from your `app/build.gradle` one. Follow the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to see exactly how your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` file should look like.

Also Firebase and Play-services need to be on the same version number. So change the dependencies to have at least the same version number.

Comment: I made

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

 and my problem was solved.